# Troca de sprites

Tags: java, eclipse, game

Olá, estou tentando fazer a animação do sprite quando recebe dano(mudando para um sprite branco), mas não estou conseguindo, segundo o próprio eclipse diz que o erro está nas ''{'' porém ao meu ver estão todas corretas, e não consigo achar erro no meu código.

```
if(!isDamaged) {
        else if(dir==left_dir){
            g.drawImage(leftPlayer[index], this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()-Camera.y,null);
        }   else {
                g.drawImage(playerDamageLeft, this.getX() -Camera.x,this.getY()- Camera.y,null);
        }
        }
        if(!isDamaged) {
            if(dir==up_dir) {
            g.drawImage(upPlayer[index], this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()-Camera.y,null);
        }   else {
                g.drawImage(playerDamageUp, this.getX() -Camera.x,this.getY()- Camera.y,null);
            }
        }

        if(!isDamaged) {
            else if(dir==down_dir){
            g.drawImage(downPlayer[index], this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()-Camera.y,null);
        }   else {
                g.drawImage(playerDamageDown, this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()- Camera.y,null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tendo problemas com as chaves e a disposição de `if..else`

Neste primeiro trecho de código:

```
if(!isDamaged) {
            else if(dir==left_dir){
                g.drawImage(leftPlayer[index], this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()-Camera.y,null);
            }   else {
                    g.drawImage(playerDamageLeft, this.getX() -Camera.x,this.getY()- Camera.y,null);
            }
        }
```

`else if` está dentro do primeiro`if`, então não deveria haver `else`, a versão corrigida seria:

```
    if(!isDamaged) {
        if(dir==left_dir){
            g.drawImage(leftPlayer[index], this.getX()-Camera.x,this.getY()-Camera.y,null);
        }   else {
            g.drawImage(playerDamageLeft, this.getX() -Camera.x,this.getY()- Camera.y,null);
        }
    }
```

O mesmo está acontecendo no último bloco